# Plugin Datatables: selecting data in a column to be sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm new with plugin DataTables in js, and i didn't find how i can select specific data to be sorted in a column. For example, in my table, i've a column with "Rating". I'd like to sort it only with the percentage and not with the other values.

```
 <td>
        <span class="rating">100.00%</span>
        <span class="voteup">3 <img src='/images/voteup.png' alt='voteup' /></span>
        <span class="votedown"> 0 <img src='/images/votedown.png' alt='votedown' /></span>
         <br /> 
        <span class="comment">0 comments</span> <br/> 
        <span class="views">17 views</span>
 </td>
```

I load data directly from the dom (generated by php), here is my DataTables generation in js.

```
var oTable;


$(document).ready(function() {

oTable = $('#BuildList').dataTable({
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bSortable": false},
        { "bSortable": false},
        { "bSortable": false},
        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
        { "asSorting": [ "desc" ] },
    ]
});

// To sort by default the column 4
oTable.fnSort([[3, 'asc']]);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['rating-desc'] = function(x,y) {

x = parseFloat($(x).first().html());
y = parseFloat($(y).first().html());

return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
$(document).ready(function() {




oTable = $('#BuildList').dataTable({
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bSortable": false},
        { "bSortable": false},
        { "bSortable": false},
        { "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },
        { "asSorting": [ "desc" ], "sType": "rating" }
    ]
});

// To sort by default the column 4
oTable.fnSort([[3, 'asc']]);

});
```